# Solr suggester tutorial/simple example for java

Tags: java, solr, autosuggest

I see some question about how to do specific things with Suggester in Solr, but how about how to actually use it? I'm stuck in how to simply query the suggest api to get the results in Java, maybe using Solrj? I just cannot find any simple tutorial that would explain it.

All I have is the SuggesterTest class that even after 3hours of trying to decode I still cannot understand how things work, especially the crazy requests that look like:

```
req("qt", requestUri, "q", "ac", SpellingParams.SPELLCHECK_COUNT, "2", SpellingParams.SPELLCHECK_ONLY_MORE_POPULAR, "true"),
            "//lst[@name='spellcheck']/lst[@name='suggestions']/lst[@name='ac']/int[@name='numFound'][.='2']",
            "//lst[@name='spellcheck']/lst[@name='suggestions']/lst[@name='ac']/arr[@name='suggestion']/str[1][.='acquire']",
            "//lst[@name='spellcheck']/lst[@name='suggestions']/lst[@name='ac']/arr[@name='suggestion']/str[2][.='accommodate']"
```

Isn't there anything simpler than this?

Also, another question, do I need to rebuild the index for the suggestions? if let's say I added some data before, and now want to use them with suggester. Do I also need to specify somewhere which field I want to query in suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Well I gave up using this, I could not make it work. Instead, I decided to use the EdgeNGrams: http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/09/08/auto-suggest-from-popular-queries-using-edgengrams/ and it works pretty good for what I need. Then in the Java code I just use a normal query.

Comment: Can you answer the question yourself, then when you can accept that answer. Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.